# UserControl in DataGridViewCell WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have my UserControl which consists of StackPanel with Label and ListBox
[image]

I need to put this UserControl in DataGridCell from code! Not from XAML! Who knows how to do this?

Comment: Not an answer, but be careful about putting to much elements in a datagrid cell. It's a performancekiller.

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

```
<DataGrid >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          your stuff goes into here...
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

same can be achieved by using code.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do a regular grid, but I belive this should translate:

```
MyNameSpace.MyUserControl theUserControl = new MyNameSpace.MyUserControl();
theUserControl.Margin = new Thickness(0);
Grid.SetColumn(theUserControl, 1);
Grid.SetRow(theUserControl, 1);
myGridDisplay.Children.Add(theUserControl);
```

Comment: myGridDisplay is DataGrid View?

Comment: myGridDisplay is the instance of the DataGrid.

Comment: There is no Children Property in DataGrid. Are you using DataGrid from WPF?